# ASP.NET Export to Excel - Lock Cells

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, office-interop

I'd like to export a table I have on my webpage to an Excel file and **lock some cells in the new file**.  Here is my current code:

```
Protected Sub btnExportToExcel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExportToExcel.Click
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=EpicSearchResults.xls")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Me.EnableViewState = False

    Dim sw As New System.IO.StringWriter()
    Dim htw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw)

    Session("tblResults").RenderControl(htw)

    Response.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

This code works in generating the Excel file. I've searched for an was unable to find much for a solution to lock cells in the new file.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Leniel said, you probably need a better library. Another one you could check out is [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). Works wonderfully.

The code in EPPlus to lock cells is `worksheet.Cells["A1:G60"].Style.Locked = true;`

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need a more powerful library to do what you want. This involves changing the way you currently export data to Excel.

Take a look at NPOI: http://npoi.codeplex.com/discussions/252597

References:

[Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c/1022518#1022518)